# Include decorated nested objects in Rails 5 & Draper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper

I am using Rails 5 and Draper to decorate a model.

My models are posts and comments and there is a decorator for comments.

I want to fetch all posts and eager load the decorated comments.

My starting point is

```
@posts = Post.all.includes(:comments)
```

But this of course does not return the decorated comments. What do I have to modify to get the rendered comments?

Answer (score 0):

From the [draper README](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#decorating-associated-objects):

> Decorating Associated Objects
>
> You can automatically decorate associated models when the primary
>   model is decorated. Assuming an `Article` model has an associated `Author`
>   object:
>
> ```
> class ArticleDecorator < Draper::Decorator
>   decorates_association :author
> end
> ```
>
> When `ArticleDecorator` decorates an `Article`, it will also
>   use `AuthorDecorator` to decorate the associated `Author`.